# Delete multiple of the same item from list

Tags: python, list

I am wondering how I would delete all items specified from a list, including all duplicates.

Here is a dumbed down version of my code, and it's only deleting half of the list each time. Wondering mostly why it doesn't delete all items at first.

```
blacklist = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1']
item = '127.0.0.1'

print(blacklist)
for _ in blacklist:
    blacklist.remove(item)
print(blacklist)
```

Comment: A quicker (and viable) way to do this would be `blacklist = [i for i in blacklist if i != item]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
deduped = set(blacklist)
deduped.remove(item)
```

To remove multiple items

```py
deduped = set(blacklist)

for item in items_to_remove:
    deduped.remove(item)
```

Comment: And perhaps finally a `list(deduped)`. Might also change the order.

Comment: He didn't specify the ordering in his question.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thanks. Just think it's weird why it's not deleting every item from the loop.

Comment: If a list contains duplicate elements, the remove() method only removes the first matching element.

Comment: Also, see the linked dupe.  Changing the length or ordering of the list while you're iterating screws up the iterator such that it no longer necessarily touches every element of the list.

Comment: From the question, I see he only wanting to remove one item, but I will update my answer to include that

Comment: Ahh, thank you Samwise, good to know! Sorry for not being specific enough in the question, James Linn, I'll think to be more specific in the future.